# How to do COUNTIFS in horizontal and vertical data with unequal number of rows?

Tags: excel, formula, excel-formula

How can I count the number of occurrences of numbers 3, 4, 5, etc. of data that meets the criteria in both horizontal and vertical positions using Excel functions?

```
A                           B       C       D
Trainer                    Q1      Q2      Q3
Terry Wong                  5       4       4
Terry Wong                  4       4       4
Terry Wong                  4       4       2
Terry Wong                  3       3       2
Maggie Ngeow Nyuk Chin      3       4       4
Maggie Ngeow Nyuk Chin      4       4       4
Maggie Ngeow Nyuk Chin      4       4       4
```

I have tried

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A8,"=Terry Wong",B:D,"=4")
```

But there is an error in it because Excel needs both range criteria to have an equal number of rows.

Can you suggest a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to do this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A8,"Terry Wong",C1:C7,4,D1:D7,4,E1:E7,4)
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading the question but, of course, COUNTIFS as suggested will only give a result of 1 in the example given (the one row with "Terry Wong" in first column and 4s in all 3 of the other columns). Is that the required answer or do you want to count all 4s in rows with "Terry Wong"?

Comment: I've understood OP wanted to check if C=4 **and** D=4 **and** E=4 but maybe you're right :)

Answer (score 3):

Just in case it's useful to anyone, here's a formula that will return the total number of 4's for Terry Wong:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A8="Terry Wong"),(B2:B8=4)+(C2:C8=4)+(D2:D8=4))
```

Comment: ...and you could also do that like this `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8="Terry Wong")*(B2:D8=4))`